# Python Regex - How to restrict a given regex pattern to a range of character

Tags: python, regex

I am using python to perform some text analysis and using regex to get required pattern from the text.

I would like to know, how can i restrict a pattern to specified number of characters.

For Eg - We have make use of {a,b} to define lower and upper bound of a specified character. How can the same logic be applied to a full pattern.

I have the following code:

```
import re
text = '''

547 U18101MH1988PTCO50073 =RAINBOW GARMENTS AND EXPORTS (INDIA) PRI
548 UU24230MH2004PTC147574 RAINBOW HERBAL AND RESEARCH PRIVATE LIMI
549 U55200MH1992PTCO067327 RAINBOW HOLIDAY-INNPVT.LTD.

550 U15100MH2004PTC148619 RAINBOW HORTICULTURE PRIVATE LIMITED

551 US9S99S9MH2000PTC124660 RAINBOW INFOTECH (INDIA) PRIVATE LIMITED
552 U70200MH2011PTC221779 RAINBOW INFRAVENTURES PRIVATE LIMITED
553 U15130MH2004P1C14/013 RAINBOW JELSTAR FOODS PRIVATE LIMITED
'''

re.findall('U.*\d{5}.*\d',text)
```

This output would give me a list of values from the text. I want to restrict the length of individual values in the list to be between 19 to 21. How can i achieve the result?

Also, out of curiosity, is it possible to get all possible matches in a given text - for eg - UU24230MH2004PTC147574 value can have multiple multiple match possible using the string provided along with the restriction of length as mentioned above?

I know i can achieve some bit of it using list comprehension but want regex to do it for me as i have complex regex query string and this is just a small component of the overall.

Thank you all

Comment: If you reach this point, maybe you should get away from regexes for the large complex match, and start _parsing_ your input string in a more programmable way.

Comment: You may utilize whitespace boundaries, [see how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67489879/3832970).

Comment: Hi, do you need more assistance with this issue? Please let know via a comment.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Thanks for checking. While my initial ask has been answered, i had a follow question, out of curiosity, regarding multiple pattern match from the same text. For Eg -  UU24230MH2004PTC147574 can have multiple match [UU24230MH2004PTC14757, U24230MH2004PTC147574]. Is it possible to do through Regex?

Comment: @AakashUdasi Only with a bit of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a lookahead to assert that the length of the matched string is between 19 and 21 chars long.

```
(?=\S{19,21}\s)U\S*\d{5}\S*
```

However, this relies on there being 19-21 chars prior to a white space.

So in the case of `UU24230MH2004PTC147574` it would match `U24230MH2004PTC147574` and ignore the first `U`.

---

```
re.findall(r'(?=\S{19,21}\s)U\S*\d{5}\S*', text)
#['U18101MH1988PTCO50073', 'U24230MH2004PTC147574', 'U15100MH2004PTC148619', 'U70200MH2011PTC221779', 'U15130MH2004P1C14/013']
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/2RNlvu/1)

Comment: Note that `.` may well be a whitespace other than newline on itself. I don't see why you'd us a lookahead here like this. Sorry to be a critique =)

Comment: The lookahead is simply to check that the pattern result is between 19-21 chars. How would you achieve this without using the lookahead?

Comment: You seemed to have missed the point I made here =). Let me [show](https://regex101.com/r/xfUueA/1) you.

Comment: @JvdV Apologies, I see. I did not double check the original pattern when writing my answer. I only added the section to limit size. I have changed the `.` now. :)

Comment: No my dv, but now you'd just match stuff like `551 U123456 RAINBOW FOODS PRIVATE LIMITED`. My point from the 1st comment still stands I'm afraid =). Btw, just positive critisicm from my end.

Comment: @JvdV No issue! I should have done some additional edge case testing. I have updated the lookahead.

Comment: Thanks @PacketLoss and JvdV for finetuning the output. This is really helpful. I am at a nascent stage when it comes to Regex. Based on the recent tutorial i took on Look ahead or Look behind, i understand that these are Zero-width assertion and does not include in the output necessarily. Wondering how in the output above, the Look ahead pattern is also included as part of the regex match. Secondly, i would also like to understand what if i placed the Lookahead pattern after the regex pattern. For Eg - If i do (r'U\S*\d{5}\S*(?=\S{19,21}\s)', text) instead, then it is not yielding the results

Comment: @AakashUdasi the lookahead needs to be before the pattern as it is looking ahead to check that the pattern matches the lookahead. If you put it after, it will look for the pattern, that must be followed by the lookahead.

Comment: @PacketLoss - Thanks a ton. This text (UU24230MH2004PTC147574) has two possible output based on the pattern. Is there a way to get both of them. Currently, it ignores the first 'U' as rightly highlighted by you, however curious what if the situation requires both the output to be extracted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
(?<!\S)(?=\S{19,21}(?!\S))U\S*\d{5}\S*\d(?!\S)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cveHAo/1/).

*Details*:

- `(?<!\S)` - left hand whitespace boundary
- `(?=\S{19,21}(?!\S))` - immediately to the right, there must be 19, 20 or 21 non-whitespace chars followed with whitespace or end of string
- `U` - an `U` char
- `\S*` - zero or more non-whitespace chars
- `\d{5}` - five digits
- `\S*` - zero or more non-whitespace chars
- `\d` - a digit
- `(?!\S)` - immediately to the right, there should be a whitespace or end of string.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/phEEjx):

```py
import re
text = '''
 
547 U18101MH1988PTCO50073 =RAINBOW GARMENTS AND EXPORTS (INDIA) PRI
548 UU24230MH2004PTC147574 RAINBOW HERBAL AND RESEARCH PRIVATE LIMI
549 U55200MH1992PTCO067327 RAINBOW HOLIDAY-INNPVT.LTD.
 
550 U15100MH2004PTC148619 RAINBOW HORTICULTURE PRIVATE LIMITED
 
551 US9S99S9MH2000PTC124660 RAINBOW INFOTECH (INDIA) PRIVATE LIMITED
552 U70200MH2011PTC221779 RAINBOW INFRAVENTURES PRIVATE LIMITED
553 U15130MH2004P1C14/013 RAINBOW JELSTAR FOODS PRIVATE LIMITED
'''
 
print( re.findall(r'(?<!\S)(?=\S{19,21}(?!\S))U\S*\d{5}\S*\d(?!\S)',text) )
```

Output:

```
['U18101MH1988PTCO50073', 'U15100MH2004PTC148619', 'U70200MH2011PTC221779', 'U15130MH2004P1C14/013']
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex works:

```
U.*\d{5}.*\d(?=\s)(?<=\S{19})(?<!\S{22})
```

We need to add the requirement for a space at the end of the match, and then ensure that there was at least 19 non-space characters before the match, and no more than 21.

Code for testing this:

```py
values = re.findall('U.*\d{5}.*\d',text)
restrictedValues = [x for x in values if 21 >= len(x) >= 19]
print(values)
print ([len(x) for x in values ])

print(restrictedValues)
print ([len(x) for x in restrictedValues ])

restricted2 = re.findall('U.*\d{5}.*\d(?=\s)(?<=\S{19})(?<!\S{22})',text)
print(restricted2)
print([len(x) for x in restricted2])
```